# Display multiple pop-ups when superposition of polygons with Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

I have a map with polygons vector objects.

Superpositions can exist between the polygons. That is to say a bigger polygon is sometimes completely above a smaller one.
With Openlayers, is it possible to display two pop-ups instead of only one (the 1st pop-up being related to the polygon above, the 2nd being related to the polygon on the bottom) ?  Or one pop-up containing the attributes of the two polygons ?

I looked for infos but didn't find a lot of stuff on that. There is that subject (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859364/display-multiple-wfs-layers-with-popup) but no answers.

Comment: cross posted and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46359498/display-multiple-pop-ups-when-superposition-of-polygons-with-openlayers)